# method pointer and inheritance // kind of strategy pattern (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, strategy-pattern

In my design, there is a class which reads information from file. The read info represents a job (for simplicity, it's an integer, which is "job id"). The file reader class can accept objects which can handle such a job. Now my idea was, to make an Interface, e.g. "IJobHandler" which has a pure virtual function "DoJob()" and then you can call something like

```
FileReader fr;
Class1 c1; // has a base class IAcceptor with virtual method HandleJobId()
Class2 c2; // has a base class IAcceptor with virtual method HandleJobId()
fr.Register(c1);
fr.Register(c2);
fr.doJob(1); // calls c1.HandleJobId()
fr.doJob(2); // class c2.HandleJobId()
```

This would work fine. But what happens, if some class can handle two or more job ids? But there is only one method which this class can implement (HandleJobId()). Wouldn't the following be nice: 
`fr.Register(c1, c1::Handle_1())` or something like that?

Maybe my intention is not very clear right now. But you will se it on the bigger code example below. Sorry for the big code block, but I don't know how to explain it that exactly...

```
class IAcceptable
{
public:
    // interface; implementors should return map of job-ids (int)
    // and a kind of pointer to a method which should be called to
    // handle the job.
    virtual std::map<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER> GetJobIds() const = 0;
};

class Class12 : public IAcceptable
{
public:
    void Handle_1(){} // method to handle job id 1
    void Handle_2(){} // method to handle job id 2

    virtual std::map<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER> GetJobIds() const
    {
        std::map<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER> intToMethodMap;
        // return map, which says: "I can handle job id 1, by calling Handle_1(), so I give you c12 pointer to this method"
        // (same thing for job id 2 and Handle_2())
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER>(1, POINTER_TO_Handle_1);
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER>(2, POINTER_TO_Handle_2);
        return intToMethodMap;
    }
};

class Class34 : public IAcceptable
{
    void Handle_3(){} // method to handle job id 3
    void Handle_4(){} // method to handle job id 4
    virtual std::map<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER> GetJobIds() const
    {
        std::map<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER> intToMethodMap;
        // return map, which says: "I can handle job id 3, by calling Handle_3(), so I give you c12 pointer to this method"
        // (same thing for job id 4 and Handle_4())
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER>(3, POINTER_TO_Handle_3);
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER>(4, POINTER_TO_Handle_4);
        return intToMethodMap;
    }
};

class FileReader
{
public:
    // register an IAcceptable
    // and add its handlers to the local list
    void Register(const IAcceptable& acc)
    {
        m_handlers.insert(acc.GetJobIds());
    }

    // if some job is to do, search for the job id and call 
    // the found function
    void doSomeJob(int i)
    {
        std::map<int, SOMEFUNCTION>::iterator specificHandler = m_handlers.find(i);
        // call here (specificHandler->second)()
    }
private:
    std::map<int, SOMEFUNCTION> m_handlers;
};


int main()
{
    Class12 c12;   // can handle job id 1 and 2
    Class34 c34;   // can handle job id 3 and 4

    FileReader fr;
    fr.Register(c12);
    fr.Register(c34);

    fr.doSomeJob(1);  // should lead to this call: c12->Handle_1()
    fr.doSomeJob(2);  // c12->Handle_2();
    fr.doSomeJob(3);  // c34->Handle_3();
    fr.doSomeJob(4);  // c34->Handle_4();
}
```

Well, maybe the design is my problem and someone can give me a hint how to make it better :)

Comment: Can every job ID be handled by at most one handler, or could there potentially be multiple eligible handlers? If so, how do you want to decide which one to use?

Comment: Why can't this be done with simple pointers-to-methods (of type `void (IJobHandler::*)(int)`)?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: all handler which CAN handle a job id, should handle it, regardless of orderness.

Comment: @imre: I tried this, but how can I do this with inheritance? How should the pointer look like, if you have only the base class pointer and the real implementation in a derived class? Maybe I did'nt get your hint and you could explain it a bit in detail?

Comment: @Johannes: You can just explicitly cast a pointer-to-member-of-derived into a pointer-to-member-of-base. This would work well as long as a derived object has the same memory address as its base subobject, that is, if `&derived == &(static_cast<Base*>(derived))`. This is always true if you only use single inheritance.

Comment: @Imre: But how can you call the method which is defined in the derived class using the base pointer?

Comment: @Johannes: Basically you store the "address" of a function defined in the derived class, but you store it in a pointer variable whose type is pointer-to-method-of-base. Then you call it on a derived object as if you were calling a base method on a base object. Yes, you're lying to the compiler, but in simple cases (single inheritance) you can get away with it, because the actual code generated is the same. It's a hack though, and wouldn't work in some cases when the pointer representation for a derived method may be different (MI). For a better, more complicated solution see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example:

```
class IAcceptable; 

class DelegateBase
{
public: 
    virtual void Call() = 0; 
};

template <class Class> class Delegate: public DelegateBase
{
public: 
    typedef void (Class::*Function)(); 
    Delegate(Class* object, Function f): func(f) {}
    virtual void Call() { (object->*func)(); }

private: 
    Class* object; 
    Function func; 
}; 



class IAcceptable
{
public:
    // interface; implementors should return map of job-ids (int)
    // and a kind of pointer to a method which should be called to
    // handle the job.
    virtual std::map<int, DelegateBase*> GetJobIds() = 0;
};

class Class12 : public IAcceptable
{
public:
    void Handle_1(){} // method to handle job id 1
    void Handle_2(){} // method to handle job id 2

    virtual std::map<int, DelegateBase*> GetJobIds()
    {
        std::map<int, DelegateBase*> intToMethodMap;
        // return map, which says: "I can handle job id 1, by calling Handle_1(), so I give you c12 pointer to this method"
        // (same thing for job id 2 and Handle_2())
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, DelegateBase*>(1, new Delegate<Class12>(this, &Class12::Handle_1)));
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, DelegateBase*>(2, new Delegate<Class12>(this, &Class12::Handle_2)));
        return intToMethodMap;
    }
};

class Class34 : public IAcceptable
{
    void Handle_3(){} // method to handle job id 3
    void Handle_4(){} // method to handle job id 4
    virtual std::map<int, DelegateBase*> GetJobIds()
    {
        std::map<int, DelegateBase*> intToMethodMap;
        // return map, which says: "I can handle job id 3, by calling Handle_3(), so I give you c12 pointer to this method"
        // (same thing for job id 4 and Handle_4())
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, DelegateBase*>(3, new Delegate<Class34>(this, &Class34::Handle_3)));
        intToMethodMap.insert(std::pair<int, DelegateBase*>(4, new Delegate<Class34>(this, &Class34::Handle_4)));
        return intToMethodMap;
    }
};

class FileReader
{
public:
    // register an IAcceptable
    // and add its handlers to the local list
    void Register(IAcceptable& acc)
    {
        std::map<int, DelegateBase*> jobIds = acc.GetJobIds(); 
        m_handlers.insert(jobIds.begin(), jobIds.end());
    }

    // if some job is to do, search for the job id and call 
    // the found function
    void doSomeJob(int i)
    {
        std::map<int, DelegateBase*>::iterator specificHandler = m_handlers.find(i);
        specificHandler->second->Call(); 
    }
private:
    std::map<int, DelegateBase*> m_handlers;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Class12 c12;   // can handle job id 1 and 2
    Class34 c34;   // can handle job id 3 and 4

    FileReader fr;
    fr.Register(c12);
    fr.Register(c34);

    fr.doSomeJob(1);  // should lead to this call: c12->Handle_1()
    fr.doSomeJob(2);  // c12->Handle_2();
    fr.doSomeJob(3);  // c34->Handle_3();
    fr.doSomeJob(4);  // c34->Handle_4();

    return 0;
}
```

1. To call a member function we need an object; so your maps should contain not simply method pointers, but something that can encapsulate a complete call: an object + a method pointer. That something is Delegate here.
2. To make sure that the method is called correctly even if it's defined in a subclass, we need to store both the derived object and the method pointer type-correctly (no casting). So we make Delegate a template, with the derived class as its parameter.
3. This means that delegates based on methods of different subclasses are incompatible, and cannot be put into a map. To work around this we introduce a common base class, DelegateBase, and the virtual function Call(). Call() can be called without knowing the exact type of stored object / method, and it will be dispatched to a type-correct implementation. Now we can store DelegateBase* pointers in the map.

Also check out boost::function and boost::bind, they provide a generalization for the above, and I think they could also be used to your purposes.

Comment: thank you very much! looks quite complicated (for someone, who doesn't deal very often with templates), but: 
- it works
- is as flexible as needed
- suits my needs
I only have to learn a bit more about these templates mixed with abstract base classes; never seen that before, but I'm still learning :)
Based on restrictions I can not use boost for this project, but anyway I'll have a look at it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to this sort of problem.

If you have a class which can handle several different jobs, in separate
functions, the simplest solution is to wrap it, several types, e.g.:

```
class JobsOneAndTwo
{
public:
    void doJobOne();
    void doJobTwo();
};

class JobOne : public AbstractJob, JobsOneAndTwo
{
public:
    virtual void doJob() { doJobOne(); }
};

class JobTwo : public AbstractJob, JobOneAndTwo
{
public:
    virtual void doJob() { doJobTwo(); }
};
```

If this occurs often in the set of jobs, you can create a template (over
two or moer member function pointers) to generate the individual wrapper
functions.

Alternatively, you can dispatch on a data member of the class:

```
class JobOneAndTwo : public AbstractJob
{
    int myJob;
public:
    JobOneAndTwo(int id) : myJob( id ) {}
    void JobOne();
    void JobTwo();
    virtual void doJob()
    {
        switch ( myJob ) {
        case 1:
            JobOne();
            break;

        case 2:
            JobTwo();
            break;
    }
};
```

In this case, you instantiate the class twice, each time passing a
different argument to the constructor.

In most of the cases I've seen, when one class can handle two jobs, it's
because the two jobs differ only in some parameters; this is really just
a variant on the second solution above, except that you don't switch to
call different member functions, you simply use the parameters (passed
into the constructor) in the basic function.

More generally, don't forget that your concrete job classes can have
data, and their behavior can be modified by such data.  And that you can
register multiple instances of a single class, with different data.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef void (IAccaptable::*SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER)(); 
...
Register(1, (SOME_KIND_OF_FUNCTION_POINTER)(&Class12::Handle1));
```

Warning: this C-style cast will only work with single inheritance. (Well, actually the cast would compile just fine with multiple inheritance too, but when calling `(derivedObject->*funcPtr)()` with a funcPtr that points at a member function of a non-first base class, then it would be called without the derivedObject pointer having been properly adjusted to point at the proper subobject belonging to that base, most probably resulting in a crash.)

A better, but more complicated solution would be to register small caller objects instead of member function pointers. When calling the handler functions, these caller objects could appropriately cast the target object.

```
class CallerBase
{
public: 
    virtual void Call(Base* object) = 0; 
}; 

template <class Derived>
struct Caller: public CallerBase
{
public: 
    typedef void (Derived::*Function)(); 
    Caller(Function f): func(f) {}
    virtual void Call(Base* object) 
    {
        Derived* derived = static_cast<Derived*>(object); 
        (derived->*func)(); 
    }

private: 
    Function func; 
}; 

Register(1, new Caller<Derived>(&Derived::F));
```

Then your map would contain CallerBase* pointers, and once you find the proper caller, you'd do `caller->Call(object)`. If `object` in this call is a Derived*, then it will be implicitly cast to Base*, but the virtual `Caller<Derived>::Call()` function will cast it back to Derived* before actually calling the method.

Comment: This actually _is_ complicated :) I'm not sure if I understand it completely, so here are some questions: what is Base? Is this IAcceptable (from my post above)? And is Derived the implementor Base (Class12, Class34 in my post above)? Maybe you can help me one more time :) In the result, I only want to call `Register(handler)` and the handler itself provides the info, which jobs it can handle, and how it can handle it. something like: `Register() {/*map.add(handler->getJobIdsWithFunctions)*/}` maybe you can tell me in more detail, how your solution works.

Comment: After giving it some more thought I realized that I've answered a somewhat different question than what you've asked :) . I posted another answer with a complete solution, I think that one is closer to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

So you say that you have many handlers, each of which can handle an arbitrary number of job IDs, and you want to register an arbitrary number of handlers and let all of them which apply handle a given job.

To that end, let every handler implement this interface:

```
struct Handler
{
  virtual bool canHandle(job_id_t id) const = 0;
  virtual void doJob(job_it_t id) = 0;
};
```

To register a handler, simply store a pointer in a container:

```
std::vector<Handler*> handlers;
```

Then, if you need to do a job, iterate the container and dispatch:

```
handleJob(job_it_t id)
{
  for (std::vector<Handler*>::iterator it = handlers.begin(), end = handlers.end(); it != end; ++it)
  {
    if ((*it)->canHandle(id))
      (*it)->doJob(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for this idea. I thought about something like this few hours ago. Problem is, that the handler itself has to dispatch again, because it can handle more than one job. something like a switch statement, switching the id. Therefore I thought it would be nice, that the Handler returns registers itself by providing a job id and a function pointer. Means e.g.: "Hey I can handle job id 420, just call my function Handle_420, oh and here is a pointer to the function, because I don't want to deal with dispatching the id."

Comment: OK, if you think that's better (though I'm not sure; you might as well implement the switching inside the handler's `doJob()`, but up to you)... then you can make a `std::multimap<job_it_t, std::function<void()>>` to store handlers; each handler has a registration method `regiser(Map &)`, and to dispatch you iterate over the `equal_range` of the multimap.

Answer (score -1):

Method pointers can be a lot of fun.

I don't want to self promote myself but check out my guide on them I wrote back in school.

http://nicolong.com/code-examples/menu-object-tutorial

Might help a little.

Comment: "I don't want to self promote myself": this is what you're doing.